# How to define another sequence $c_n$ from $a_n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

I'm lost as to how to complete the following question:

For any sequence $a_n$ define another sequence $c_n$ by the formula
$$c_n = na_0+(n−1)a_1+· · ·+2a_{n−2}+a_{n−1}.$$ 
Find an expression for the generating
function $C(z)$ of the sequence $c_n$ in terms of the generating function $A(z)$ of the sequence $a_n$.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence $(c_n)$ is just the convolution of $(a_n)$
with the sequence $0,1,2,3,\ldots$. So what is the GF of that sequence?

Answer (score 0):

Hint. Note that
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}nx^n=x\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n\right)=x\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}.$$
Now recall what a [Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function#Convolution_.28Cauchy_products.29) is.